# Where Does Lichess Get Its Names for the Openings?

Tags: opening, lichess

On lichess.org, when you turn the opening book on in an analysis board, you get names for the openings. For example, after 1.e4 d6 2.d4 Nf6 3.Nc3 c6, lichess says the opening is called "Czech Defense." Many openings have standard, accepted names, but sometimes there is disagreement, especially with deep variations. There is also sometimes disagreement between different playing platforms. For example, sometimes chess.com uses different names than lichess. What sources provide lichess all of the names?

Comment: It would be interesting if you could give some examples of disagreements between lichess and chess.com and ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: See for example 1. d4 d5 2. Bf4, which Lichess calls the "Mason Variation" and Chess.com calls the "Accelerated London System."

Comment: One rare name I've seen is Maroczy for Tartakower for Fantasy variation

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Lichess is open source. That source includes a table of openings compiled by the contributors to lichess.

https://github.com/lichess-org/chess-openings

And if you want to see who exactly made what change/addition to the list, you can click on the `.tsv` file in question and examine the history.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: Only if we neglect the immediate followup "Good grief, where do the contributors come up with all those obscure names..." :-)

Comment: @HaukeReddmann: Well, to quote the linked page: *"Improvements, additions and fixes are welcome."*

Comment: And if you want to see who exactly made what change/addition to the list, you can click on the .tsv file in question and examine the `history`.

Comment: I prefer “blame”: it's a much clearer (albeit sometimes inaccurate) way to see whose fault something is.